Mathematica crashes when changing the cell style
I am using Mathematica 13.2.1.0 on Windows 10.
I have experienced it crashing in many notebooks, specifically when changing the cell style, e.g., from Input to text.
How to prevent that?

Please show reproducible example.

There is no reproducible example; sometimes, when I click on cell style, Mathematica crashes and closes, whatever the content of a notebook is

If you get a replicable example, please send the notebook and instructions to Technical Services here.
